# PHP print from database without 'while'

Tags: php, mysql, database, printing

I need to print one row from a table so a while loop isn't necessary, is there any other method?

Answer (score 3):

You need not while.

Just do your while condition outside while 1 time.

i.e

```
$a=mysql_fetch_row($sql);
//use $a
```

instead of

```
while($a=mysql_fetch_row($sql)){
    //use $a
}
```

Comment: Although you should be using PDO.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (($dbResult = mysql_query("SELECT ... FROM ... LIMIT 1")) !== false)
{
  $row = mysql_fetch_array($dbResult);
  echo $row['Column_Name'];
}
```

Just fetch one row, no need to always loop a retrieval.

Answer (score 1):

```
$results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE user_id = 1234");
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($results);
echo ($row['user_id']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Do what you would have done inside the condition of your loop, and you'll be fine.